# What does "almost everywhere invertible" mean?

Tags: measure-theory, definition, inverse-function

I'm reading the [paper](https://math.wvu.edu/%7Eadtudorascu/Gangbo-Tudorascu-2017.pdf) *On differentiability in the Wasserstein space and well-posedness for Hamilton–Jacobi equations* in which there is a paragraph

> There is a special non-commutative group related to the isometry $\sharp: \mathbb{H} / \sharp \rightarrow \mathcal{P}_{2}\left(\mathbb{R}^{d}\right)$, namely the set $\mathcal{G}(\Omega)$ of Borel maps $S: \Omega \rightarrow \Omega$ (they lie in $\mathbb{H}$ ) that are almost everywhere invertible and have the same law as the identity map $\operatorname{id}$.

Here

- $\Omega$ is the ball of unit volume in $\mathbb{R}^{d}$, centered at the origin.
- $\mathbb{H}:=L^{2}\left(\Omega, \mathrm d x, \mathbb{R}^{d}\right)$.

My naïve guess is that "almost everywhere invertible" means the Lebesgue measure of $\{\omega \in \Omega \mid \operatorname{card}(S^{-1}(\omega)) \le 1\}$ is $1$.

Could you elaborate on this notion?

Answer (score 1):

When something happens almost everywhere, this means by definition that the set of points where it doesnt happens has zero measure. In your situation, the set of points where maps $S$ are not invertible has zero measure.
$m(\{x\in\Omega|S(x)$ not invertible$\})=0$.

Comment: Could you explain what "$S(x)$ not invertible" means?

Comment: On these points, you cant define the invert of $f$. For example, $f(x)=x$ is invertible almost everywhere in $\mathbb{R}$ because the invert of $f(x)$,$f^{-1}(x)=\frac{1}{x}$ which does not define on $x_0=0$ where we now that $m(\{0\})=0$.

Comment: You meant $\{\omega \in \Omega \mid \operatorname{card}(S^{-1}(\omega)) \le 1\}$?

Comment: I mean that, the set of points that you cant define the invert of $S$ has zero measure. For example, if $f(x)=1\forall x\in\mathbb{Q}$ and $f(x)=0\forall x\in\mathbb{R}-\mathbb{Q}$ then you can say that $f(x)=0$ almost everywhere, because the set of points where $f(x)\neq 0$ which is $\mathbb{Q}$ has zero measure.

Comment: Can you define "set of points that you *can't define the invert* of $S$ has zero measure" in a rigorous term?